# Custom DataGridView, BindingSource and settings in Design Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I'm writing my own DataGridView.

1. In the VS designer Mode we can pick a source of data in "Choose Data Source" (BindingSource). But I have to fill it up in Page_Load whit data. This, however, does not cause loading them to MyCustomGrid control, and so I have to load them into `MyGrid.DataSource`. In normal dgv this is no longer needed. What could I be missing?
2. In the VS designer Mode we can manipulate with GridColumns (names, types, etc.). 
   In `MyCustomGrid` I copy all the columns and rows from the DataSource to show them later, for example in groups. Any changes force to draw the whole `MyGridView` from the beginning.

Is there any way to retrieve these properties entered in VS DesignerMode to my control without the need to write your own containers storing those data?

Comment: Can you please expand on what exactly your trying to do, at the moment the question is too vague to understand. 

So far from the question, I gather you have created a custom Datagrid (from scratch?) and when attaching a datasource (via VS design mode) it does not load, however if you write it programatically then it works.

Secondly you want to be able to access your custom properties?

Darknight

Comment: 1. I would like to now how doese the standard grid now when to load data after :
sourceMobile.DataSource = Portal.MobileTable;
//the sourceMobile is the DataSource(BindingSourse) in VS design mode
this is all what have to be don to see content of that table in gridview. In my customGrid to have the same result I must do somthing like this:
sourceMobile.DataSource = Portal.MobileTable;
customGrid.DataSource = sourceMobile.DataSource;

Comment: 2. yes, those, that are saved in Form_Name.Designer.cs file. In standard grid they are attached to it when page load. I am building my grid from basic so I would like to load them when I'm genereting and seting columns in it.